# Use and display of real-time user experience data in web applications

Tags: dashboard, real-time-updates, metrics

I recall a while back that Zendesk displayed what felt like a 'real-time' feed on performance metrics that reflects some measure of the overall user experience (which for customer support is probably customer satisfaction) that they called [Zendesk Benchmark](https://www.zendesk.com/benchmark-your-support).

I would like to know if anyone has seen anything similar for a web application or service that shows this type of information, and what type of metrics might be suitable for a real-time user experience 'dashboard' display?

Answer (score 0):

The DTA's [Performance Dashboard](https://dashboard.gov.au/) seems to be the closest thing I have found that tracks user experience related performance and displays the information publicly.

As stated on the website:

> The Performance Dashboard makes data open and accessible by measuring
> the performance of Australian government services against the Digital
> Service Standard.
>
> This promotes government transparency and helps drive the ongoing
> improvement of government services — for all Australians.

And you can see a snapshot of the information presented, and the KPIs that are measured:

- User satisfaction - The overall satisfaction rate with the service.
- Cost per transaction - The estimated cost to government, per transaction, for administering the service.
- Digital take-up - The adoption rate for the digital service.
- Completion rate - The overall rate of completion for users of the service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. For anything similar to a web application or service that shows this type of information:

Ans: I'd prefer Google Analytics to explore this domain. They eventually decluttered the organization of data components, done well.

[image: Google Analytics Real Time Overview]

2. What type of metrics might be suitable for a real-time user experience 'dashboard' display?

Ans: It depends on the goal of the business. For a government agency, there are two types of end users, government-side users and public-side users. For the gov-side, the super admin might want to track if each feature is properly usable to track, for example, criminal rate. Here, the KPI can be the case accepting rate/support ticket (Task completion rate).

For the public-side, the KPI can be the case creation rate (Task completion rate).

Hope, it helps you a bit. Thanks.